# Are interfaces necessary for simple shared methods?

Tags: oop, interface, abstraction

Is there any benefit of using an interface simply because a group of objects share a couple of public methods?

For example, I have `GameObject`, `GameComponent`, and `GameLevel`. Each have functions `onUpdate()` and `onDraw()`.

Should I create an `IGameEntity` interface that contains `onUpdate()` and `onDraw()` and have each object implement it? I don't have an intention of storing any kind of list of `IGameEntity`'s or any similar situation where I only need access to those two functions, so is this level of abstraction constructive?

Comment: YAGNI applies here I think. You can always define this interface later if you *do* end up wanting to use it.

Comment: Very true, with minimal changes to function declarations. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @aceads0529 Interface is a sort of contract that a class fulfills so if you want a class to necessarily implement some functions you should use interface to ensure that as its a good programming practice

Comment: In my opinion, using interfaces when you don't have a need for polymorphic behaviour hinders program comprehension.  If I see an interface, I expect there to be a use for it.  If there is not, it just seems like clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to bother, as you can refactor it later if needed. (Unless the code is part of a public API, in which case its users should be considered.)

Interfaces are *meaningful constraints on types*. Generally, I'd say that an interface called `IGameEntity` sounds questionable. What *is* it? From its functionality, it might as well be called `IUpdatableDrawable`, but this name already shows that it would be an oddball. It is sometimes necessary to introduce concepts like this, but this is a cost in terms of readability that should only be paid with good reason.

A good interface gives a name to a set of features that belong together. Just like in spoken language, there's little point in naming a concept without use cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no advantage to doing this.  Here's the key statement:

> I don't have an intention of storing any kind of list of `IGameEntity`'s or any similar situation where I only need access to those two functions.

The purpose of interfaces is to decouple *intent* and *implementation*.  This allows a consumer to call the interface methods without introducing a dependency on the implementation.  It also allows new implementations to be substituted in without affecting consumers.

But all of these advantages only apply *if somebody is using the interface*.  If there is no useful situation for a group of heterogeneous implementers (e.g. a list of `IGameEntity` objects) then the interface provides no value.  (In fact, the presence of the interface may lead consumers to believe they *should* be using lists of `IGameEntity` objects when there was no reason to do so.)

Answer (score -1):

If you have different implementations in yous classes for these methods you should use interface, on the other hand if you have a basic implementation for methods you can use abstract class.

Answer (score -1):

If `onUpdate()` and `onDraw()` methods are required for these three classes, then yes, you need to create the interface and implement it. In other way you cannot be sure, that all three classes has `onUpdate()` and `onDraw()`implementations.
And it will be better to call interface as `IGameEntityFunction`.